# do all Fancybox3 slideshow images have to be on parent page?

Tags: css, fancybox, slideshow

I want to make a slideshow with Fancybox3 (I'm using Dreamweaver 5.5). I have a lot of portfolios of images but I don't want to put a thumbnail of every image on the parent pages. I just want to put the thumbnail of the first image in each series on the parent page. Is this possible?

Comment: What do you mean by "parent page"?

Comment: By parent page I mean the page that shows the thumbnails, where you click on the thumbnails and the slideshow pops up. I would like to only show the first thumbnail on that page. Thanks

Comment: Similarly to the last example of this demo - https://codepen.io/fancyapps/pen/mqEMGX?editors=1000 ?

Comment: great. Thank you!

Comment: but I just realized: I have a lot of large images I would have to hide on a single html page, which would make it close to 14mb. Is there a way to store the images somewhere else, that would be downloaded only if a visitor got that far in a slideshow?

Comment: The script does what it does. You either add click event to elements or start programmatically (see docs). The rest is up to you.

Comment: I haven't done click events before, have only encountered them in my kid's Tynker lessons. Can click events activate scripts outside of the original page? Sorry such an amateur. Thanks.